# Simple Recursive Prolog Function

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm currently trying to create a simple function that prints the integers in a list given the first and last number.

For example, the function call: count(3,7,Z) would print "Z = [3,4,5,6,7]"

Here is my attempt so far:

```
count(First,Last,Result):-
  First <= Last,
  append(First,Result,Result),
  count(First+1,Last,Result).
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? The idea is that as long as First is less than or equal to last, the sequence will keep being appended to the Result List.

Thanks in advance! I've been battling this for quite a while!

Answer (score 1):

line by line:

1. `count(First,Last,Result):-`

   bad style: the name suggest another functionality
2. `First <= Last,`

   the 'less or equal' operator is =<
3. `append(First,Result,Result),`

   you're passing INT,LIST,LIST, but append/3 has signature LIST,LIST,LIST, and
   you want a value update, but variables in Prolog are 'immutable', such call could succeed only if Result doesn't change
4. `count(First+1,Last,Result).`

   arithmetic expressions must be *explicitly* evaluated, here you pass a structure +(First,1)

And you also miss to code the behaviour required when the test (once corrected) will fail. What about `First>Last` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your program. First, when you write `3 + 2` Prolog does not, as any other language do, calculate the result. You must explicitly ask to do the calculation and bind the result of the calculation to a variable by the predicate `is`, e.g., `X is 3 + 2, ...` and then you will have `X` bound to `5` to be used in the rest of the rule's tail.

Second, writing `append(First, Result, Result)` means "by appending `First` to `Result` you obtain again `Result`", which will always fail (read: produce `false`) unless `First` is the empty list, because if you append something to a list, you obtain a longer list than the one you started with. You clearly failed in distinguishing the two `Result`s in `append` and `count` - they are really not the same. Note also that `append(A, B, C)` applies to lists, so `A`, `B` and `C` must all be lists or terms that can be instantiated to lists, or it will fail. That's precisely your case since `First` is always a number - definitely not a list, but a *member* for it. So you shall not use `append`: Use list construction and unification with `=` to append an element to a list and bind the obtained result to a variable, e.g., `X = [Element | List]`.

Finally, were all of the above correct, your predicate would nevertheless fail because you do not define the base case of the induction. In other words: When your predicate should answer `[]`? This must happen when, as CapelliC remarks, `First > Last`: In that case the range is empty, and `Result` must also be. In your program, when this happens, the predicate plainly fails (note that, when you write `foo(X, Y) :- X >= 0, Y is X + 1.`, this means failure whenever `X` is less than zero). Being the empty range the base case of the recursion, the evaluation of your predicate will, sooner or later, end there, and so it will always fail.

In the end, you should write something like:

```
ints(First, Last, Interval) :- First > Last -> Interval = [] ;
  NFirst is First + 1, ints(NFirst, Last, NInterval), Interval = [First | NInterval].
```

(I gave more declarative names to your predicates and variables). Of course this predicate will work only when invoked with First and Last completely instantiated to numbers (it cannot be inverted).